# Android camera crash, repeating images, native nav buttons messed up

Tags: android, nexus-5

I have a bar-code scanning Cordova (webview) app, and after a certain point, if I restart the barcode-scanning camera, I get a crazy crash that bricks my phone until I give the entire phone a full restart:

[image]

Stats:

Nexus 5
Android 4.4.4
Kernel 3.4.0-gd59db4e

I'm using the zbar scanning lib, which uses OpenCV.

Here's the catlog right around the time that things go haywire; once I start getting "Failed to get_buf", the repeating image effect kicks in and I have to restart my phone.

`D/mm-camera(199): module_faceproc_port_event_func:667] FD_STREAMON for stream 10004
I/mm-camera(199): cpp_module_handle_streamon_event:1983, identity=0x10004, stream-on done
I/mm-camera(199): isp_streamon: E, session_id = 1, stream_id = 4, stream_type = 5
I/mm-camera(199): wb_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
I/mm-camera(199): wb_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
I/mm-camera(199): wb_set_params: param_id is not supported in this module
D/mm-camera(199): module_faceproc_port_event_func:825] MCT_EVENT_MODULE_ISP_OUTPUT_DIM stream info 1920x1080 identity 10004 10003
I/mm-camera(199): isp_ch_util_streamon: session_id = 1, channel_id = 3, already active.
I/mm-camera(199): ispif_streamon: session_id = 1, active_streams = 3
I/mm-camera(199): mct_pipeline_process_set: Stream on/off returned
D/mm-camera-intf(186): mm_stream_qbuf: Starting poll on stream 0xb7f4c4cc type :5
D/mm-camera-intf(186): mm_stream_qbuf: Started poll on stream 0xb7f4c4cc type :5
D/mm-camera-intf(186): mm_stream_qbuf: Starting poll on stream 0xb7f4bda4 type :1
D/mm-camera-intf(186): mm_stream_qbuf: Started poll on stream 0xb7f4bda4 type :1
D/mm-camera(199): module_faceproc_client_schedule_mode:1808] apply 3 report 2 new_mode 0
E/mm-camera-sensor(199): port_sensor_handle_upstream_module_event:1244 Reset previously set LED state!
I/AEC_PORT(199): aec_port_proc_downstream_event: Received LED state timeout. Reset LED state!
D/mm-camera(199): module_faceproc_client_schedule_mode:1808] apply 0 report 3 new_mode 0
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_cur_pos_after_lens_move: After move: FV: 1689470 CurPosition: 36
D/mm-camera(199): module_faceproc_client_schedule_mode:1808] apply 1 report 0 new_mode 0
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_cur_pos_after_lens_move: After move: FV: 634118 CurPosition: 33
D/dalvikvm(3354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3373K, 35% free 17228K/26472K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(3354): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.818MB for 3110416-byte allocation
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_cur_pos_after_lens_move: After move: FV: 602020 CurPosition: 30
D/dalvikvm(3354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 24% free 20265K/26472K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
D/dalvikvm(3354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3037K, 35% free 17227K/26472K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(3354): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.818MB for 3110416-byte allocation
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_cur_pos_after_lens_move: After move: FV: 552162 CurPosition: 27
D/dalvikvm(3354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 24% free 20265K/26472K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
E/mm-camera(199): cpp_module_process_frame_control:1458 failed: wrong queue for mct_type = 2 frame 8 exp 16
E/mm-camera(199): cpp_module_process_frame_control:1458 failed: wrong queue for mct_type = 2 frame 8 exp 16
E/mm-camera(199): cpp_module_process_frame_control:1458 failed: wrong queue for mct_type = 2 frame 8 exp 16
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_cur_pos_after_lens_move: After move: FV: 524040 CurPosition: 31
D/dalvikvm(3354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3037K, 35% free 17227K/26472K, paused 13ms, total 14ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(3354): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.818MB for 3110416-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(3354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 24% free 20265K/26472K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
E/mm-camera(199): cpp_module_process_frame_control:1458 failed: wrong queue for mct_type = 2 frame 9 exp 17
E/mm-camera(199): cpp_module_process_frame_control:1458 failed: wrong queue for mct_type = 2 frame 9 exp 17
E/mm-camera(199): cpp_module_process_frame_control:1458 failed: wrong queue for mct_type = 2 frame 9 exp 17
D/dalvikvm(3354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3037K, 35% free 17227K/26472K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(3354): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.818MB for 3110416-byte allocation
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_cur_pos_after_lens_move: After move: FV: 328800 CurPosition: 33
D/dalvikvm(3354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 24% free 20265K/26472K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
D/dalvikvm(3354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3037K, 35% free 17227K/26472K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(3354): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.818MB for 3110416-byte allocation
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_cur_pos_after_lens_move: After move: FV: 370341 CurPosition: 35
D/dalvikvm(3354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 24% free 20265K/26472K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
D/dalvikvm(3354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3037K, 35% free 17227K/26472K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(3354): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.818MB for 3110416-byte allocation
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_cur_pos_after_lens_move: After move: FV: 398033 CurPosition: 37
D/dalvikvm(3354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 24% free 20265K/26472K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_cur_pos_after_lens_move: After move: FV: 397856 CurPosition: 39
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_cur_pos_after_lens_move: After move: FV: 424101 CurPosition: 41
D/mm-camera-intf(186): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stoping poll on stream 0xb7f4bda4 type :1
D/mm-camera-intf(186): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stopped poll on stream 0xb7f4bda4 type :1
D/mm-camera-intf(186): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stoping poll on stream 0xb7f4c4cc type :5
D/mm-camera-intf(186): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stopped poll on stream 0xb7f4c4cc type :5
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_cur_pos_after_lens_move: After move: FV: 440796 CurPosition: 43
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_cur_pos_after_lens_move: After move: FV: 438574 CurPosition: 41
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_update_focus_status: AF Status already updated to output!Return!
I/mm-camera(199): af_util_update_focus_status: AF Status already updated to output!Return!
E/mm-camera(199): mct_stream_metadata_bus_msg:Failed to get_buf
E/mm-camera(199): mct_stream_metadata_bus_msg:1259: NULL ptr
D/mm-camera-intf(186): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stoping poll on stream 0xb7f4af54 type :8
D/mm-camera-intf(186): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: Stopped poll on stream 0xb7f4af54 type :8
E/mm-camera(199): mct_stream_metadata_bus_msg:Failed to get_buf
E/mm-camera(199): mct_stream_metadata_bus_msg:1259: NULL ptr
E/mm-camera(199): mct_stream_metadata_bus_msg:Failed to get_buf
E/mm-camera(199): mct_stream_metadata_bus_msg:1259: NULL ptr
E/mm-camera(199): mct_stream_metadata_bus_msg:Failed to get_buf
E/mm-camera(199): mct_stream_metadata_bus_msg:1259: NULL ptr`

Any ideas?

Comment: I can confirm this issue with Nexus 5. Test same build on Galaxy Tab(4.4.2), Nexus 4 (L), Galaxy(4.1.2) – works fine.

Comment: @roma we're finding that the crashes occur reliably if we've opened the native keyboard before, but doesn't show up if we haven't opened the keyboard. Can you try a keyboard-less version of your app and see if the issue is still occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer posted by my colleague at the following link solved our problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284543/914123

> OK we had the same problem - Nexus 5 only, but with ZBar lib instead of ZXing.
>
> The issue was resolved by switching from a SurfaceView to a TextureView - however this resulted in slower frame rates.
>
> Through testing we found that our issue was caused by leaving the screen, bringing up the keyboard and going back - our solution was setting android:windowSoftInputMode to AdjustPan in the manifest.